# Django: Use query result in future queries instead of repeating it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a custom user profile model. This model has `can_edit` property that uses `ContentType` and `Permission` objects to determine if the user has permission or not. I'm using this property within serializer and it works fine, but is terribly inefficient, as per each user the `ContentType` and `Permission` are queried again.

It seems like `prefetch_related` could fit here, but I don't know how to apply it, as these objects are not referenced directly through some properties, but kinda queried separately. Is it possible to fetch the `ContentType` and `Permission` beforehand and just use the results in further queries?

Here's my model:

```py
class CustomProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def can_edit(self):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Article)
        permission, _ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(
            codename="edit", name="Can edit", content_type=content_type
        )
        return self.user.has_perm(self._permission_name(permission))

    def _permission_name(self, permission):
        return f"{permission.content_type.app_label}.{permission.codename}"
```

My current query:

```py
User.objects.order_by("username").select_related("profile")
```

My serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    can_edit = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="profile.can_edit")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "is_active",
            "is_staff",
            "can_edit",
        )
```

In fact, I have more than one property with similar content to `can_edit`, so each user instance adds around 6 unnecessary queries for `ContentType` and `Permission`.

How can I optimize it?

Comment: not sure if this is what you want but checkout cached_property https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property

Comment: no, there are multiple objects, each of them will call its own property which might have different value, and all of them are repeating the same queries underneath

Comment: "*, I have more than one property with similar content to `can_edit`*" On this `UserSerializer` class or some other class? @Djent

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - in the same class

Comment: @Djent Can you add an example of it? (maybe I can provide an accurate solution)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu it has almost the same content as `can_edit`, but different permission name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, Django already has done it for us.

Here change your **`can_edit(...)`** as below.

```
class CustomProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def can_edit(self):
        return self.user.has_perm("app_name_article.can_edit")
```

Here, the [**`user.has_perm()`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/) is beautifully built in an efficient way

#### Note

- I don't think we need to find out the ***<app_label>_<model_name>*** string in a *"programmatic"* way.

Comment: This is surely the **"recommended"** solution!  It's much better to cache the result of a check rather than caching the steps necessary to perform said check (especially when it's builtin).  Do **note** that this comes with caveats, for example, you will need to repopulate the cache if you are programmatically adding a permission to a user, then immediately checking it.  See the docs on **[`Permission Caching`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I mean, I still kinda need to get the permission names programmatically, but I can cache them as a class attribute for `CustomProfile`.

Comment: @Djent *"....I still kinda need to get the permission names programmatically...."*, Unfortunately, I don't see any such situation in this ***given context***. IMHO, use *hard-coded strings* instead of *programmatic way* (in this situation)

Answer (score 0):

Use a __init__ special method to initialize any propertys/variables that you need to use more then once.

Example:

```
class CustomProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwarg):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Article)
       self.permission, _ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename="edit", name="Can edit", content_type=content_type)

    @property
    def can_edit(self):
       return self.user.has_perm(self._permission_name(self.permission))
```

Now you can use these values in your methods.

Comment: But it still will be repeated multiple times as the multiple profile objects will be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing the query, you can use `prefetch_related` in combination with `Case...When` [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField

qs = User.objects.prefetch_related('user_permissions').annotate(
      can_edit = Case(
      When(user_permissions__codename='edit_article', then=True),
      default=False, 
      output_field=BooleanField())
     )

# check the results
>>> [(i.can_edit, i.username) for i in qs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@cached_property` instead of `@property` to cache `can_edit`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property